# C# cannot convert object type array to string type array while using AutocompleteStringCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I want to use texbox autocomplete using database. The database query returns a list of names using join statement from three tables. Now I got an erorr when using .ToArray():

Error: "Can not convert Source type Purchase[] to target type string[]"

Here is my code:

```
PurchaseManager _aPurchaseManager = new PurchaseManager();

string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName();

productNameTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
productNameTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;


var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
autoComplete.AddRange(productNameFromJoinedDatabase);
productNameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
```

Update:

After using:

```
       string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName().Select(x => x.ProductName).ToArray();
```

The previous error has gone. But it's not working for autocomplete!

Here is my Purchase Class:

```
class Purchase
{
    public Int64 PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double TotalPurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public CategoryEntry CategoryEntry { get; set; }
    public BrandEntry BrandEntry { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Purchase()
    {
        CategoryEntry = new CategoryEntry();
        BrandEntry = new BrandEntry();
        Product = new Product();
    }
}
```

Here is my database class:

```
public List<Purchase> GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName()
    {

        List<Purchase> _aPurchaseList = new List<Purchase>();

        _connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT CategoryEntryTable.Name, BrandEntryTable.Name, ProductNameExtentionEntryTable.ProductNameExtention " +
                                     "FROM ProductNameExtentionEntryTable " +
                                     "JOIN CategoryEntryTable " +
                                     "ON ProductNameExtentionEntryTable.CategoryId = CategoryEntryTable.CategoryId " +
                                     "JOIN BrandEntryTable " +
                                     "ON ProductNameExtentionEntryTable.BrandId = BrandEntryTable.BrandId");
        _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
        SqlDataReader aReader = _command.ExecuteReader();

        if (aReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (aReader.Read())
            {
                _aPurchase = new Purchase();
                _aPurchase.CategoryEntry.Name = (aReader[0]).ToString();
                _aPurchase.BrandEntry.Name = (string)aReader[1];
                _aPurchase.Product.ProductNameExtention = (string)aReader[2];

                _aPurchaseList.Add(_aPurchase);
            }
        }
        _connection.Close();
        return _aPurchaseList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `_aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName().Select(x => x.ProductName).ToArray();` or whatever is the right product name property.

The problem here (I think) is that `GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName` is returning an array of `Purchase` instead of names, so the extra `Select` is to get just the names.

If you think it should be returning names instead, then try fixing the method to return just the names.

Update: To get a combined name, you can use something like this:

```
_aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName().Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", x.CategoryEntry.Name, x.BrandEntry.Name, x.Product.ProductNameExtention)).ToArray();
```

Not that the `string.Format` is joining them (delimited by space but you can use any character to delimit) into one string.

Comment: It fixes the error, but I want to retrieve CategoryName, BrandName, ProductName. x => x.ProductName only will retrieve ProductName, right? And the code is not working for autocomplete!

Comment: I'm going to add my database code, so that I will be able to make it more clear.

Comment: But you can't put all those in a string array unless you join them into a string somehow.

Comment: I've updated the code above. join them into a string? I've joined them using a query from three databases. May be I don't understand you this time?

Comment: I believe you'd have to call `autoComplete.AddRange();` multiple times, each time adding the range of keywords you want to filter with. So something like `autoComplete.AddRange(productNameFromJoinedDatabase); autoComplete.AddRange(categoryNameFromJoinedDatabase);autoComplete.AddRange(brandNameFromJoinedDatabase);`. Correct? I 'm saying this because it seems that `AddRange` only accepts string array.

Comment: So, I need to get data from those three different tables and will have to call autocomplete.AddRange(); each time? Such as, autoComplete.AddRange(productNameFromProductDatabase); autocomplete.AddRange(CategoryNameFromCategoryDatabase); autocomplete.AddRange(BrandNameFromBrandDatabase); But I need the name will be combined using CategoryName, BrandName and, ProductName. So that I can save the combined name using this autocomeplete text box.

Comment: Great! Yes, it solved the problem! Thank you. : ). Is there any way to add you here? or contact you in another way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add you here". And contact you in what sense? Email? I get notified if you tag me (@mrchief)...

Comment: Yes, email perhaps if you have no problem, or facebook. I can tag you when I post any question here?

Comment: You can, although there are many smart people here who can help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName()` returns an array of `Purchase` objects, and it's telling you that you can't simply stuff that into a string array.

```
string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase
    = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName();
```

You'll have to do the conversion yourself, most likely selecting the property you need for autocompletion.

Perhaps something like this (untested), assuming the "Name" property is a string in the "Purchase" class, and that it's what you want to base your auto-completion on:

```
var purchases = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName();

autoComplete.AddRange(purchases.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't see where else the error could be happening, I'll assume it's in your second line.

```
string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName();
```

I'll also assume that `PurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName()` returns type `Purchase[]` rather than string.

There's two ways to fix this, that functionally are the same, but performance-wise are a little different.  The fast way:

```
Purchase[] purchases = _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName();
string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase = new string[purchases.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < purchases.Length; i++)
{
    productNameFromJoinedDatabase[i] = purchases[i].ProductName; // where ProductName is the name you're trying to get
}
```

The second way is a teeny bit slower, but prettier in my opinion.  That's to use Linq;

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] productNameFromJoinedDatabase =
    _aPurchaseManager.GetProductNameWithCategoryAndBrandName().Select(purchase => purchase.ProductName).ToArray();
```

Comment: I've read the previous answers, but I guess I'm missing something. If I only use purchase.ProductName, my need will not be fulfilled as I need to combined ProductName with CategoryName and with BrandName. So that I've written a query which returns a list of combined name. Now I need to put the list into the autocompleteStringCollection. Am I missing something from your answer? Sorry I don't understand fully I guess.

Comment: That comment was for @dfoverdx. His answer is a duplicate of already posted answers.

Comment: @Mrchief When I started posting this, no answers had been given yet.  By the time I finished, two had sprung up.  :)